# C# arrays to C++ vectors

Tags: c#, c++

What is the equivalent from C# to C++ of doing this:

```
int[n][num] card;
someFunction(card[0]);


someFunction(int[] card)
{
    ....
}
```

Using **vectors** in C++

---

Also

Is this code in C++:

```
std::vector< std::vector <int> > a(numA, vector<int>());
```

equivalent to this code in C# ?:

```
int[][] a = new int[numA][];
```

If it is not, please tell me how it should be.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector<vector<int> > card(n, std::vector<int>(num));
someFunction(card[0]);

someFunction(vector<int> vec)
{
    ....
}
```

This:

```
std::vector< std::vector <int> > a(numA, vector<int>());
```

and simpler

```
std::vector< std::vector <int> > a(numA);
```

are C++ jagged arrays equivalent to:

```
int[][] a = new int[numA][];
```

Comment: This worked for me! Both answers are good.
Another thing: Do you know the equivalent of copying an array like this `a[n].CopyTo(array, 0)`?

Comment: @iLQ, if `a` and `array` are vectors then `array.insert( array.begin(),a[n].begin(),a[n].end() );`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know C# but this looks right

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > card;
someFunction(card[0]);


void someFunction(const std::vector<int>& card)
{
    ....
}
```

Use `&` to indicate that you are passing the vector by *reference* to avoid the overhead of copying the vector itself. If you want `someFunction` to modify the vector then drop the `const`.

Your other code looks OK too.

Comment: A slightly more precise _equivalent_ would be to use `.at(0)` instead of `[0]`. :)

Comment: @iLQ You should do exactly what I said, a vector is like a 1D array.